# C++ Triangulation library in a Java Application

Tags: java, c++, integration, path-finding, triangulation

I'm implementing an algorithm for pathfinding that is a variant of A* (HPA*) but with a triangulated search space. I've been making a Java application and have written a good amount of code, but I recently found a C++ library that already takes care of the triangulations for the project. I have several options but I'm not sure what I should do: convert the library to Java or integrate the C++ code into my Java library. I could also rewrite my code in C++ but I'm not very familiar with the language.

This application tests the performance of an algorithm for a paper I'm writing so it doesn't need to be portable. What do you think my best option is?

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Comment: Is it advisable/possible to integrate C++ code into a Java application? The rest of the post is context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to call C++ code from Java, read up on the Java Native Interface (JNI) coding conventions.

But generally, unless you have an extremely good reason to cross languages, it's more trouble than it's worth. How complicated is the triangulation code? If it's less than a few hundred lines, I'd suggest reimplementing; if it's more than a few thousand, using a library may be justified but you should probably check whether there's a Java library available or if someone has already written the appropriate JNI glue code.

Comment: He should also consider that rewriting the c++ code in java, will need some more testing to the whole process (to make sure nothing was broken), writing new unit-tests, etc.

Comment: Here's the code: http://graphics.ucmerced.edu/software/tripath/index.html. I'm fairly certain there isn't a Java version.

Comment: So the code is several hundred KBs (good triangulations are a complex thing) - it's certainly not reasonable to attempt to port this to Java. In fact, I've also been looking for a good Java Triangulation library for a while now, but there hardly seems to be one. I once started writing a JNI connection to http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html, which kind of works, but is not (yet) publishable. You might want to try http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/jtem/numericalMethods (contains Ruppert/Delaunay triangulators). It does not handle more complex shapes, but may be sufficient for your use-case

Comment: OK, so this does sound like a good argument for either writing JNI glue code... or giving up on Java and moving the whole project to C++.